# Pass spinner selected items to Textview from 1st fragment to 2nd fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, bundle, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners in `FragmentOne.class` Searched a lot from stackoverflow, none answers my case

- fromcountryspinner
- tocountryspinner

when selected items from spinner, they should be displayed in 2 `Textviews` which are in `FragmentTwo.class`

Used in `FragmnetOne.class`:

```
 btnsend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("countryfrom", fromcountryspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            bundle.putString("countryto", tocountryspinner.getSelectedItem().toString());

            FragmentTwo fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);            


`getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragment).commit();

            }
        });
```

in FragmentTwo.class getting that values:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_car_page, container, false);
TextView txtfromcountry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_fromcountry);
 TextView txttocountry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_tocountry);

    String countryfrom = this.getArguments().getString("countryfrom");
    txtfromcountry.setText(countryfrom);
    String countryto = this.getArguments().getString("countryto");
    txttocountry.setText(countryto);
return view;
}
```

The app crashes. when clicked in crashlog, it points the class **FragmentTwo.clas** any ideas whats goind wrong?

Logcat: I have changed names of fragment class so that to make understandable: OrderCarPage is `FragmentTwo.class`

```
10-08 13:44:42.247 27801-27801/datasite.com.aroba E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                    at datasite.com.aroba.OrderCarPage.onCreateView(OrderCarPage.java:69)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:997)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:764)
                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your logcats..

Comment: code looks fine. show your logs

Comment: ordercarpage from where it is called?

Comment: what is line number 69 in OrderCarPage.java ?

Comment: OrderPage.class is renamed as just FragmnetTwo.class. to make more clear for others, i have written FragmentTwo

Comment: This is my line 69 in OrderPage:
String countryfrom = this.getArguments().getString("countryfrom");

Comment: Please anyone help me to fix it. I am unable to find solution. looked through many tutorials and stackoverflow posts, but not result positive

Comment: @J_J_J show the code of class `FragmnetTwo` and try to remove the this. may be you re calling it with wrong context.

Comment: Buddy, You just need to place your bundle code inside onViewCreated(override methid). you are trying to fetch value inside onCreateView that leads to crash. 
Hope it helps.

Comment: @Harminder Singh, it is now working totally. its in wrong way.